# c# columnheader looking is different at the windows form editor ,compared to the compiled version

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

i am kind of new at c#.And i am detecting a problem with my gui :( project.
How the title says,the columnheader looking at the windows form editor  is different ,compared to the compiled version,specifically the font.

PS:the EnableHeadersVisualStyle property is already put on false.

*Editor looking*
[visual studio gui editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRAcp.png)

*Compiled version*
[visual studio gui editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73hZs.png)

I have tried to set the wished properties at the  properties pane ,and also at the  constructor.

```
    public Historial()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var font = SystemFonts.GetFontByName("Century Gothic");
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = font;
        if (font == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Null","Null");

        }

    }
```

the variable "font" return null because cant find the system font :(

I hope somebody can help me.Thanks for answer

Comment: Century Gothic is not a system font. You can load a non system font via new Font(...)

Comment: Thanks,i will try, and :,),will post the results

Comment: using new Font() worked nice ,thanks